# Upstart after VirtualBox shared folder mounted

Tags: mount, virtualbox, upstart, shared-folders

I have written an upstart like the one below:

```
start on vagrant-mounted
respawn

script
        cd /media/sf_ACEBot
        exec /usr/bin/mono /media/sf_ACEBot/ACE\ Bot.exe >> /media/sf_ACEBot/log.txt
end script
```

but it does not start on startup. I believe it is because `/media/sf_ACEBot` is not mounted yet. The mount happens automatically by VirtualBox guest additions and it is not in fstab file.

how should I configure my upstart?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by adding a sleep time at the beginning

```
start on runlevel[2345]
respawn

script
        sleep 5
        cd /media/sf_ACEBot
        exec /usr/bin/mono /media/sf_ACEBot/ACE\ Bot.exe >> /media/sf_ACEBot/log.txt
end script
```